# Android Intent Image Gallery

Tags: android, android-intent, android-studio

I have two activity in my application(MainActivity and CheckActivity).
MainActivity Intent to CheckActivity and in CheckActivity Intent to Gallery Application for choose image.
But when return from Gallery Application it always return to MainActivity.
How can I return to CheckActivity when return from Gallery Application.

This is my code.

MainActivity.java

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, CheckActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

CheckActivity.java

```
Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

It's always return onActivityResult in MainActivity.java and requestCode = 1.

Thank you very much.

Comment: can you put full code?

Comment: That is strange. Your code is ok. Is there something you did not show us? A finish() in the onActivityResult() of CheckActivity?

Comment: Thank you for reply. I found finish() in onStop()

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, CheckActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

Instead of these lines you use

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, CheckActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, CheckActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you put finish() into your CheckActivity after

```
Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,   android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
finish();
```

if you remove finish() it will work fine...

Comment: Thank you for reply. I found finish() in onStop()